# Error mark in eclipse/pydev when running ipython -i

Tags: python, eclipse, ipython

I work interactively on data in a ipython console. I have a small script which I can use to Import new data, but normally I want to keep the old data in RAM too. So what I did is to add the following piece of code to the Import script:

```
try:
    data_list.append(data)         
except NameError:
    data_list = [data]
```

I execute this script from the ipython console with run -i scriptname.py. This adds the new data to the data_list, or creates a new list if it doesn't exist. This works basically fine.

Now the question: in eclipse/pydev, I get an error sign, because the Parser recognizes that data_list has not be assigned before. Is there any way to make the error sign disappear?